# Add zero padding to numbers in a column by using str_pad in string package

Tags: r, string

I want to use the `string str_pad` function to make a column in my desired format, which includes zero padding the numbers in the "Code" column to 3 digits.

I've run this code:

```
Animals %>%
gather(most_common, cnt, M:OG) %>% 
group_by(name) %>% 
slice(which.max(cnt)) %>%
arrange(code)
```

Which resulted in the following tibble:

```
Code      Name       most_common
32       Monkey        Africa
33       Wolf          Europe
34       Tiger         Asia
35       Godzilla      Asia
#With 1 234 more rows
```

I'm happy with my code above. **However, because I'm going to merge this df later on, I need the "Code" column to be three digits with zero padding (i.e. in the format "nnn" / "032"), as this:**

```
Code      Name       most_common
032       Monkey        Africa
033       Wolf          Europe
034       Tiger         Asia
035       Godzilla      Asia
#With 1 234 more rows
```

I've run `string str_pad($code, $3, $0)`, but it doesn't work. I guess there's something wrong there. Should I run this code wherever I want in my chunk or by using `%>%`?

Comment: Alternative: `df %>% mutate(Code = paste0(0,Code))`.

Comment: Shouldn't all the references to a `"string"` package be `"stringr"`? I would simply edit, but because OP does not include failure example, it's unclear what went wrong. Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "Code      Name       most_common
32       Monkey        Africa
33       Wolf          Europe
34       Tiger         Asia
35       Godzilla      Asia", header = T)

df %>% 
  mutate(Code = str_pad(Code, width = 3, pad = "0"))

#>   Code     Name most_common
#> 1  032   Monkey      Africa
#> 2  033     Wolf      Europe
#> 3  034    Tiger        Asia
#> 4  035 Godzilla        Asia
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulS . It worked when I used `mutate(Code = str_pad(Code, width = 3, pad = "0"))` together with the first code I mentioned. :)

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we can use `sprintf`

```
df1$Code <- sprintf("%03d", df1$Code)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option could be using `formatC` with "d" for integer and a flag "0" the prepending zero like this:

```r
df$Code <- formatC(df$Code, width = 3, format = "d", flag = "0")
df
#>   Code     Name most_common
#> 1  032   Monkey      Africa
#> 2  033     Wolf      Europe
#> 3  034    Tiger        Asia
#> 4  035 Godzilla        Asia
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>